# charAt() return not a string?

Tags: java, char

I'm trying to write some code that will tell me if the first letter of one string equals the first letter of another. I can't figure out how to compare a string to the return of charAt(). Help?

```
   public class CharAtTest
    {
        public static void main(String [] args)
        {
            String name = "joe";
            String initial = "j";
            if(initial.equals(name.charAt(0)))
            {
                System.out.println("Sucess");
            }else{
                System.out.println("Fail");
            }

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could use:

```
if (initial.charAt(0) == name.charAt(0))
```

or better

```
if (name.startsWith(initial)) {
```

Comment: +1. Just an additional comment, if the Strings are going to be dynamic, it might be a good idea to test the `string != null` and `string.length() > 0` before testing for equality using `charAt()`

Comment: `String.isEmpty()` would be better than `String.length()>0`

Answer (score 1):

charAt(), like the name implies, returns a char, not a string. So make `initial` a char instead.

Answer (score 1):

Simply do this:

```
String name = "joe";
char initial = 'j';

if (name.charAt(0) == initial) {
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way would be:

> String.valueOf(name.charAt(0));

Or:

> Character.toString(name.charAt(0));

But the implicit way (see ivanovic's answer) works as well

> name.charAt(0) + ""